# Can I change the triangle image on the drop down in the top-nav in zurb foundation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu, navigation, zurb-foundation

I am using [zurb foundation framework](https://github.com/zurb/foundation), I would like to change the triangle image of the drop down on the top-bar nav menu to a cog. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the vanilla CSS and JS, or the [foundation gem](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/applications.html)? Assuming it's the gem go into `foundation_and_overrides.scss` and Remove the triangle using:

```
$topbar-arrows: false; //Set false to remove the triangle icon from the menu item
```

Then you can add custom css to put a cog there instead. Below is the original css for the triangle, which was creating using a very small inset border, if you want to make sure you're matching the proper margins etc,

```
.top-bar-section .has-dropdown > a:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: inset 5px;
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) transparent transparent transparent;
    border-top-style: solid;
    margin-top: -2.5px;
    top: 22.5px; }
```

**Edit**  Here is some CSS which gets nearly there, except `margin-right` being overridden by some of foundation's css... Should help though

```
.top-bar-section .has-dropdown > a:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  background-image:url('https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/imod/512/Hardware/pignon.png');
  background-size:15px 15px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:center; 
}
```